# Extracting unique entries from log

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a log file which prints out lines in the following format:

```
ERROR [10 Dec 2013 03:57:07] ........ Project ID: [88000317019]......
```

I want to count the number of unique project IDs which have errored.
Each Project ID may emit an error multiple times.

How do i do it?

Comment: Are the leading `.` literal or do they represent something? Depending on what is before `Project ID:` many posted solution would break!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -F[][] '/ERROR/ {a[$4]++} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-F[][]` set `[` and `]` as possible field separators.
- `/ERROR/ {a[$4]++}` create an array with the values `a[ key1 ]=num_of_ocurrences_key1, a[ key2 ]=num_of_ocurrences_key2`, etc. `$4` is used because it is the text appearing inside the `[]` brackets and makes it the 4th position. `/ERROR/` filters the lines containing the text `ERROR`.
- `END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}` print the results.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
ERROR [10 Dec 2013 03:57:07] ........ Project ID: [88000317019]......
ERROR [10 Dec 2013 03:57:07] ........ Project ID: [88000317019]......
WARNING [10 Dec 2013 03:57:07] ........ Project ID: [88000317019]......
ERROR [10 Dec 2013 03:57:07] ........ Project ID: [88000317013]......
WARNING [10 Dec 2013 03:57:07] ........ Project ID: [88000317010]......

$ awk -F[][] '/ERROR/ {a[$4]++} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' a
88000317019 2
88000317013 1
```

Comment: I guess we need to find only ERRORs not INFO/DEBUG/WARNINGS

Comment: Just made an edit to the post - a fact i should have mentioned before. The ID is not actually the first entity within [] on a line.Can the above solution tweak accordingly?

Comment: Exactly, @IUnknown, what BMW says should make it. As you accepted the answer I guess the issue is solved. Otherwise, ping me!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for any contents before and after the part you are looking for and **only** for those lines that log `ERROR`:

```
$ cat file                                                                     
.............Project ID: [xyz] ERROR...........
.............Project ID: [abc] INFO............
.............Project ID: [abc] ERROR...........
.............Project ID: [xyz] WARNING.........
.............Project ID: [xyz] ERROR...........

$ grep -Po '(?<=Project ID: [[])[^]]+(?=[]] ERROR)' file | sort | uniq -c        
      1 abc
      2 xyz
```

*Note: Requires `GNU grep`.*

Comment: could you explain the ?< and ?= (coorelated with - Po i presume) [no gnu grep here]

Comment: They are called [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and are part of PCRE *(which `-P` turns on with GNU Grep)* when joined with the `-o` options they increase the complexity of output you get with a single call to `grep` significantly.

Comment: so like in full ("recent") RegEx spec and thus needing a GNU grep. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
awk '
{
   match($0,/\[(.*)\]/,a)
   id[a[1]]++
}
END {
   for(i in id) 
      q++
   print "Number of unique ids: " q
}' log.file
```

Comment: You really should warn people when using gawk-only constructs like a 3rd arg for match() so they don't waste their time trying to use and debug it if they don't have gawk as their default awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for pointing it out.. I was not aware that it was gawk-specific..

Answer (score 0):

other ways.

```
sed -n '/ERROR/ s/.*\[//;s/\].*//p' infile|sort |uniq -c |sort -n
```